# Can't Connect my GitHub repo to Netlify and Cloudflare pages

Tags: github, netlify

I was trying to connect my Hugo website GitHub repo to Netlify and I couldn't connect. This is the error I got.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NymrX.png)

I even tried to connect to Cloudflare Pages and got the same error. Therefore, the problem is related to GitHub and not with these website hosts.

Does anyone know what's the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/35026

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by removing the organisation which more repository :

goto settings->organisations in your github account.
then leave the organisations
retry to connect to github
happy coding !!